# Kafka consumer `fetch.min.bytes` not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I wanted to consume more than 1 message at a time so configured the property `fetch.min.bytes` but still ended up consuming one message at a time.

There are more than 50k messages in the Kafka topic(6 partitions). Each message is of approx. 10KB and the property `fetch.min.bytes` is to set to 100KB (100000 bytes).

I am expecting the returned count of records should be more than 1.

Using the .net Library for consumer. Using this function to consume the data

https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.IConsumer-2.html#Confluent_Kafka_IConsumer_2_Consume_CancellationToken_

I am also not able to understand the returned type of `.consume(CancellationToken)` is `ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue>` how can I accept `List<ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue>>` as there is not such function available with `List<ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue>>` as return type.